# Como passar dados via get?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Estou com um problema. Preciso criar uma página que liste todos os registros com a categoria selecionada.

> Código onde a pessoa seleciona a categoria e ao clicar, envia para a
>   página. (Esse código está funcionando em perfeito estado, apenas coloquei para melhor compreensão.)

```
<h2 class="titulos">Categorias</h2>
   <div class="cat-lista list-group">
      <?php  
         $contador = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT categoria, count(id) as catqtde FROM postagens group by categoria");

         while($prod = mysql_fetch_array($contador)) { 

      ?>

     <a href="categoria.php" name="categoria">
        <?php echo $prod['categoria']; ?>
           <span class="badge bt-span badge-pill"><?php echo $prod['catqtde']; ?></span>
     </a>
        <?php } ?>
</div>
```

> Código da página que deveria listar os dados com tal categoria.

```
<?php 
    $ident = $_GET['categoria'];

$sqlstring = "SELECT * from postagens where categoria = $ident order by id DESC ";
  $query = @mysqli_query($mysql->con, $sqlstring);



  while ($dados = @mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
      setlocale(LC_TIME,'pt_BR','pt_BR.utf-8','portuguese');
      date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
      $datinha = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($dados['agendado']));
?>


        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-all-post" > 
            <div class="card post-item shadow">
                <a href="postagem.php?id=<?php echo $dados['id'] ?>&<?php echo slug($dados['titulo'])  ?>"><img class="card-img-top post-item-img" src="<?="admin/img/".$dados['foto']?>"></a>
                <div class="card-body">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                    <div class="categoria-span cat-span-post">    
                        <a href="#"><span><?=$dados['categoria']?></span></a>
                    </div><!--categoria-span-->
                    <div class="info-span-blog">
                        <span><img src="assets/img/icon-cal.png"><?= $datinha ?>  </span>
                    </div><!--info-span-->
                </div>
                    <a href="postagem/<?php echo $dados['id'] ?>/<?php echo slug($dados['titulo'])  ?>"><h4 class="card-title d-flex align-items-end"><?=$dados['titulo'];?></h4></a>
                        <a href="postagem/<?php echo $dados['id'] ?>/<?php echo slug($dados['titulo'])  ?>"><h5 class="card-title"><?=$dados['subtitulo']?></h5></a>
                </div><!--card-body-->
            </div><!--card-->
        </div><!--col-lg-->



 <?php   

}
$mysql->fechar();

?>

    </div>
```

O erro que me aparece é esse:

> Notice: Undefined index: categoria in D:\Arquivos\USBWebserver
>   2\root\site\categoria.php on line 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para pegar o dado enviado por GET você precisa colocar os parâmetros no seu href. Veja:

```
<a href="categoria.php?categoria=valorDoParametro" name="categoria">
    <?php echo $prod['categoria']; ?>
       <span class="badge bt-span badge-pill"><?php echo $prod['catqtde']; ?></span>
 </a>
```

Assim na outra pagina vc pega esse valor do jeito que vc fez mesmo

```
$ident = $_GET['categoria'];
```

O que você esta errando é na hora de declarar o parâmetro via link, não funciona se você apenas colocar um "name" no seu href.

Answer (score 0):

Neste trecho aqui:

`<a href="categoria.php" name="categoria">`

faça assim:

`<a href="categoria.php?categoria=<?php $prod['categoria']; ?> " name="categoria">`

Digamos que tenha uma categoria chamada Teste, a url vai ficar assim:

`categoria.php?categoria=teste`, desta forma, este trecho `$ident = $_GET['categoria'];` vai reconhecer a variável GET.

**Explicação**

Quando querer passar algo por GET, sempre coloque na URL assim:

`url.php?nomedoparamento=valor`

Se quiser mais de um parâmetro, passe assim usando o &:

`url.php?parametro1=teste&parametro2=teste2`